# Manipulate the Text for Date

Tags: vba, excel

I have the text details as below in my excel sheet, I required to extract only Dates from the below text with the help of VBA Code.I couldn't able to use formula like MID as well because the date's are either single digit OR Double digit.Please help me.

Debit_Coverage_Report_1_2_2016_11_8_34

Debit_Coverage_Report_10_11_2015_14_19_33

Comment: is the prefix allways "Debit_Coverage_Report_" ?

Comment: And where are the dates and other numbers? hour/min/seconds?
Debit_Coverage_Report_dd_mm_yyyy_hh_mm_ss?
So report 1 is Feb 1st 2016?

Comment: @sagar have you tested any of the answer below ? did they work ? any feedback ?

Comment: Sorry for the late Reply Sir, Yes its Working Absolutely Correct and Fine.Thank you so much for your help...

Comment: Dear Sir Also want to understand with regards to the code which is ---> "ReDim Preserve DateArr(0 To ind - 1)"

Comment: @sagar it's to resize the array to the number of elements actualy exists (not the empty ones). if it solved your post mark as answer (click the little **V** next to my answer below)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your prefix of "Debit_Coverage_Report" stays for all of your strings, and **"_1_2_2016"** is in the date order of `dd_mm_yyyy` (01-Feb-2016), try the Code below (VBA solution):

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExtractDate()

Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, ind As Long
Dim MyArr   As Variant
Dim DateArr() As Date

' init Date array to a lrage size on init >> will optimize it's size later in the code
ReDim DateArr(0 To 1000)
ind = 0 ' <-- init DateArr array index

' modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
With Sheets("Sheet1")

    ' in my test all data is in column B, so looking for last row with value in column B
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ' loop through all cells in columns B
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If .Range("B" & i).Value <> "" Then ' <-- check if the cell is not empty
            MyArr = Split(.Range("B" & i).Value, "_") ' <-- split the string to array elements

            DateArr(ind) = DateSerial(MyArr(5), MyArr(4), MyArr(3)) ' <-- inserting the array to DateArr array
            ' the line below is just to show you the results on column C (next to your original string)
            .Range("C" & i).Value = DateArr(ind)

            ind = ind + 1
        End If
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve DateArr(0 To ind - 1) ' <-- resize array to number of array elements found in worksheet                   
End With

End Sub
```

Screen-shot below shows the results in Column C after running this code

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to convert text to columns
In your spreadsheet, select the column, go to DATA TAB, select Text To Columns.

From there, use a delimiter "_" instead of the default TAB (Select Other) and finish

You will end up with as separate columns

```
Debit   Coverage    Report  1   2   2016    11  8   34
Debit   Coverage    Report  10  11  2015    14  19  33
```

from there party on the data to your heart's content.